# Meaning of this quote: "There is nothing new except what has been forgotten."

Tags: meaning, quotes, proverbs

I need help analyzing this quote, which is supposed to be something that Marie Antoinette said:

> There is nothing new except what has been forgotten.

What does it mean?

Comment: I expect she said it in French.

Comment: There is nothing that is essentially new. People often say that something totally new is happening, but the reality is that they're merely not aware that it's happened before. (It's disappeared from the collective memory.)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how this site works and what questions are considered on-topic.

Comment: @MickSharpe I expect she didn't say it at all. I think it's a quote from Abraham Lincoln's third inaugural address in 1869. At least that's what it says on the internet.

Comment: @deadrat Well... I'm sure I don't believe you. Either she pinched it from him or he pinched it from her.

Comment: This is clearly **off-topic**, unless there's a specific grammatical point then we can't accept it.

Comment: It seems to me that this question amounts to asking about the meaning of a proverb—though a proverb more widely recognized as being a proverb in French than in English. Still, questions about the meaning of proverbs are on topic at EL&U, just as questions about the meaning of proverbial and idiomatic phrases are. I would reopen this question.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia article on [Rose Bertin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_Bertin), a milliner and dressmaker for Marie Antoinette, Bertin is the person responsible for the quotation:

> Bertin is said to have remarked to Marie Antoinette in 1785, when presenting her with a remodelled dress, "*Il n'y a de nouveau que ce qui est oublié*" ("There is nothing new except what has been forgotten.").

An article in the My 1820 issue of *The Edinburgh Review, Or Critical Journal* on the subject of "[Education of the Poor in France](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7UY7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA498#v=onepage&q=%22de%20nouveau%22&f=false)"—cited by Wikipedia!—largely corroborates that attribution:

> A proverb of which no nation makes such frequent application as the French, and which, as history relates, was the favourite maxim of the most inventive and academic of dressmakers, Mademoiselle Bertin, is, 'Il n'y a de nouveau que ce qui est oublié;' and we think the history of these didactic inventions affords a striking proof of its justice.

So a reviewer writing for a Scottish publication in 1820 asserts that the saying in question was a French proverb, and one that Marie Antoinette's dressmaker especially liked. That is probably as close to the queen as the proverb's origin is likely to get.

As Edwin Ashworth indicates in a comment above, the sense of the saying is that what strikes us as new and different is in all likelihood merely old and forgotten—but recently rediscovered as if it were new. In a world where everything that can be done has been done (such as in late eighteenth-century France, evidently), there is nothing new under the sun, so the best one can do for surprise, excitement, and the appearance of innovation is to resurrect something old that no one remembers.